# Get text instead of ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query in which I am getting `Department_Id` as **812** its Integer value. I have referenced this ID with text in another table which is

```
select type_desc from type_mst_a where master_mkey = 812
```

and my query is

```
select convert(varchar(15),doc_Date,103)Doc_Dates,department_id, 
         case outward_Type when 'N' then 'None' when 'P' then 'Private' when 'C' then 'Confidential' 
         end [Type], convert(varchar(15),ref_date,103) Ref_dates, convert(varchar(15),Updated_Bill_Date,103)Updated_Bill_Dates ,
         convert(varchar(15), Due_Date,103)Due_dates,* from view_A_Inward_Doc_Tracking_Hdr 
         where delete_flag='N'  and mkey= 227381
```

How to get the value of that ID ?

[image: IMG]

Comment: In your query, there is no reference to the `department_id`.

Comment: @SamuelRenold:  sorry, Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-select to convert the `department_id` to a text as follows:

```
select convert(varchar(15), doc_Date, 103) Doc_Dates,
       (select type_desc from type_mst_a where master_mkey = department_id),
       ...
```

Alternatively, you could join the table `type_mst_a`.

```
select convert(varchar(15), doc_Date, 103) Doc_Dates,
       department_id,
       text.type_desc,
       case outward_Type when 'N' then 'None' when 'P' then 'Private' when 'C' then 'Confidential' end [Type],
       convert(varchar(15), ref_date, 103) Ref_dates,
       convert(varchar(15), Updated_Bill_Date,103) Updated_Bill_Dates,
       convert(varchar(15), Due_Date, 103) Due_dates,
       *
from   view_A_Inward_Doc_Tracking_Hdr INWARD
left outer join type_mst_a text on text.master_mkey = department_id
where  INWARD.delete_flag = 'N'
and    mkey = 227381
```

The outer join guarantees that - if no suitable text can be found - the result of the query does not vanish.

Comment: join is giving error, though UR first one worked for me. Error is **Ambiguous column name 'delete_flag'.**

Comment: This means that the `delete_flag` exists in both tables `VIEW_A_INWARD_DOC_TRACKING_HDR` and `TYPE_MST_A`. You can avoid having this error by indicating from which table the column `DELETE_FLAG` should be taken. I will adapt my post.